# Alguien que se maneje en sentencia PDO bindParam, les agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

SELECT * from contacto_empresa inner join empresa  on empresa.id_empresa = contacto_empresa.empresa_id_empresa 
WHERE estado_contacto = 'ACTIVO' AND id_contacto_empresa != 0

Comment: Podrías aclarar cual es tu pregunta y que error se te está presentando?

Comment: @Tridam, lo que sucede es que tengo una tabla contacto de la empresa y quiero que solamente se muestren los que tienen como estado ACTIVO

Comment: hola.. usa el boton [edit] para agregar toda la informacion necesaria a la pregunta. mira [ask]. si tu pregunta es sobre base de datos, debes mostrar el resultado obtenido, el que querias obtener y unos datos de prueba. si es sobre codigo, debes mostrar el codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero sea lo que buscas:

Trae todos los contactos activos, de todas las empresas

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from contacto_empresa INNER JOIN empresa ON empresa.id_empresa = contacto_empresa.empresa_id_empresa WHERE contacto_empresa.estado = 'ACTIVO');
$stmt->execute()
```

Trae todos los contactos activos para una empresa en particular (Una Sola) pasandole el `id` de la empresa en  `$idEmpresa`

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from contacto_empresa INNER JOIN empresa ON empresa.id_empresa = contacto_empresa.empresa_id_empresa WHERE contacto_empresa.estado = 'ACTIVO' AND id_contacto_empresa = :idEmpresa');
$stmt->bindParam('idEmpresa', $idEmpresa);
$stmt->execute()
```

Comment: Gracias @rendor9

Answer (score 0):

Sería algo así:-

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * from contacto_empresa inner join empresa on empresa.id_empresa = contacto_empresa.empresa_id_empresa WHERE estado_contacto = :estado AND id_contacto_empresa != :idEmpresa');

 $stmt->bindParam(':estado', 'ACTIVO');
 $stmt->bindParam('idEmpresa', '0');

 $stmt->execute()
```

Comment: gracias, pero aun me sigue mostrando todo los datos de la tabla contacto empresa yo solamente quiero que se vean los que tienen el estado ACTIVO